# golang code organization: where should I put custom error types that are only relevant to one function?

Tags: go, code-organization

I have just started working on my first golang project and really like the idea of returning custom error types from functions and using type assertion in the calling code, to check for specific errors. I find this solution cleaner than always comparing error messages.

My only question is: where do you best put these custom error types?

Say a number of custom error types is only used (returned) by one utility function, should they go in the same package as the function? Should I group them somehow? Or maybe there's a better way of doing this kind of thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Same package" would be my initial thought. There may be cases where having them in a different package would make sense, but that would only be if they're legitimately "the same error" from functions in multiple packages, with none of those packages being the logical "most owner".